# Move Negative Numbers to the left, first come fist list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to move negative numbers to the left.

```
using System;

class Class1
{
    static void rearrange(int[] arr, int n)
    {

        int j = 0, temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < 0)
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                j++;     
            }
        }
    }

    static void printArray(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Console.Write(arr[i] + ",");
    }

//Call the Method
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, -4, -7, 4, -2, 6, -9 };
        int n = arr.Length;
        rearrange(arr, n);
        printArray(arr, n);
    }
}
```

The question expects the output  {  -4, -7,  -2,  -9, 1, 4, 6 }
But my output is {  -4, -7,  -2,  -9, 1, 6, 4 }, because the code is to switch -9 with 4. 
How to adjust the code?

Comment: If you’re just looking for a quick solution, you could use LINQ for this: `arr.OrderBy(x => x > 0).ToArray()`

Comment: @poke Actually you'd want `x >= 0` so that 0 isn't mixed in with the negatives.

Comment: @poke Actually I'm not expecting them in the order. I think the question is to keep the original sequence of the positive numbers. Because 4 appears before 6 in the previous array

Comment: @SirenC The LINQ solution does keep the original order and only sorts by whether a number is positive or negative.

Comment: @Poke thanks for the hint, i do have a LINQ class tomorrow, i will try it~

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use LINQ?
Here is the code which does what you need using LINQ:

```
var list = new[]{ 1, -4, -7, 4, -2, 6, -9 };
var newList = list.Where(x => x < 0).Union(list.Where(x => x >= 0)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", newList));
```

Output:

```
-4, -7, -2, -9, 1, 4, 6
```

Comment: Thanks! It does make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that the code is always swapping a negative number with the number that's in the position where the negative number should go. This becomes a problem when there are a few positive numbers in a row, because the order is disturbed when a positive number in a low index is swapped with a negative number in a high index. This happens when `i` is `4` and `-2` is swapped with `1` (so at that moment the array looks like `{ -4, -7, -2, 4, 1, 6, -9 }`); and again when `i` is `6` and `-9` gets swapped with `4`, which leaves you with the result that prompted your question.

To resolve this, you have to swap the negative number with the number before it in an inner loop, until the number before it is also negative, so that the numbers retain their relative positioning:

```
static void Rearrange(int[] arr)
{
    // Start at index 1 since the first item can't move left
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            // Walk backwards from the current index, swapping items as we
            // go, until the item in the previous index is also negative
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            {
                // If previous item is negative, we can stop
                if (arr[j - 1] < 0) break;

                // Otherwise, swap this item with the previous item
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before the last iteration, the array is in this state:

> { -4, -7, -2, 4, 1, 6, -9}

You algorithm then swaps -9 and 4:

> { -4, -7, -2, **-9**, 1, 6, **4**}

Why would you expect 6 to be the last number in the array?

If you want numbers to be ordered, C# provides an `.OrderBy` extension method, but that would also change the order of the negative numbers.

Comment: Actually I'm not expecting them in the order. I think the question is to keep the original sequence of the positive numbers. Because 4 appears before 6